# Performance effective solution for multiple wildcard mask searches in msbuild?

Tags: performance, msbuild, wildcard, file-search

I'm creating msbuild project, and one of the tasks is to find all files in directories which satisfies any of file masks provided.

I realized that even if I create just one-line `Item` with several wildcards in `Include` / `Exclude` attributes, msbuild fully re-scans whole directory hiearacrhy for **each** of these wildcards.

So, if full directory scan like `($Path)\**` takes say 6 seconds, then using just 10 wildcards will make it one minute long - which is reasonably slow for my purposes.

I suppose that scanning for files is really **slow** operation, while mask compare (one or ten or thousand per filename) should be more times **faster** - so what I look for is solution which effectively scans directory hierarchy for several file masks.

Here is sample msbuild project which shows what I mean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyPath>C:\Windows</MyPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="Warmup;CheckOne;CheckTwo;CheckFive">
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Warmup">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Item1 Include="$(MyPath)\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CheckOne">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Item2 Include="$(MyPath)\**\*.exe" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CheckTwo">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Item2 Include="$(MyPath)\**\*.dll" Exclude="$(MyPath)\**\System32\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CheckFive">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Item3 Include="$(MyPath)\**\*.exe;$(MyPath)\**\*.dll" Exclude="$(MyPath)\**\System32\**;$(MyPath)\**\SysWOW64\**;$(MyPath)\**\winsxs\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

First it scans full windows directory to "warm up" FS and put anything it could to cache, then it looks for single mask, then for two masks (one include and one exclude), then for five masks (two include and 3 exclude).

When I run it with `/v:diag` switch I receive the following timings:

```
Target Performance Summary:
        0 ms  Build                                      1 calls
     6196 ms  CheckOne                                   1 calls
     7942 ms  Warmup                                     1 calls
    15030 ms  CheckTwo                                   1 calls
    39249 ms  CheckFive                                  1 calls
```

So what I see is that in average each mask adds 6-8 seconds to results.

Similar results can be seen for example using `procmon` which shows that msbuild really search all masks one by one on the same file hierarchy.

In general, what I'm looking for - how to make `CheckFive` target to take more or less the same time as `CheckOne` task.

To prove myself that enumerating files is slow I created custom task, which enumerates directory hierarchy just ones, and applies several masks to each file - and yes, it take more or less the same time for any reasonable number of masks.

But I still think I'm doing something wrong - can I achieve the same efficiency with pure msbuild?